# Running node.js forever as daemon

Tags: linux, node.js, centos, forever

I configured forever to run my node.js server on startup. using this scipt. It works fine. and forever keeps the server running. However, when I run forever list, I don't see my server here! I know it's running but it's never in this list. It looks like that the system is running two instances of forever.

```
root@ddd [/etc/init.d]# chkconfig  --list |grep node1
node1 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

This is the script:  /etc/init.d/node1

```
NAME=node1
NODE_BIN_DIR=/usr/local/bin
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
APPLICATION_DIRECTORY=/home/user1/www
APPLICATION_START=node1.js
PIDFILE=/var/run/node1.pid
LOGFILE=/var/log/node1.log

PATH=$NODE_BIN_DIR:$PATH
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH

start() {
    echo "Starting $NAME"
    forever --pidFile $PIDFILE --sourceDir $APPLICATION_DIRECTORY \
        -a -l $LOGFILE --minUptime 5000 --spinSleepTime 2000 \
        start $APPLICATION_START &
    RETVAL=$?
}

stop() {
    if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
        echo "Shutting down $NAME"
        forever stop $APPLICATION_START
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        RETVAL=$?
    else
        echo "$NAME is not running."
        RETVAL=0
    fi
}

restart() {
    echo "Restarting $NAME"
    stop
    start
}

status() {
    echo "Status for $NAME:"
    forever list
    RETVAL=$?
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        status
        ;;
    restart)
        restart
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: {start|stop|status|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: forever is user specific. Is it possible your startup script is running under a different user than what you're logged in as?

Comment: Yes, how can I check who's running forever

Comment: ps -aux | grep forever The first column is the user.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother wasting my time with trying to daemonise forever.

pm2 is the new king! forever is dead, trust me

here is how to run pm2 as a systemd or OS equivalent service:

```
npm install -g pm2

pm2 startup
```

now you can do:

```
service pm2 status|start|stop|restart
```

also:

```
pm2 save
```

will take a snapshot of your running pm2 apps and will restart them all on reboot (no crontab entries required)

finished!

pm2 is MUCH better than forever. It does exactly the same as forever but more!

```
pm2 list # equivalent to forever list

pm2 start app.js --name "wotever" # equivalent to forever start

pm2 start app.js -i 0 --name "wotever" # load balance your app on all available cores
```

Did you see that last command? Do you understand what this means? I'm in awe!

Typically your app runs on one core. Not any more! We are talking speed!

PM2 FOREVER!

Comment: I suppose this got down voted because it didn't answer the question of how to daemonize forever js, but honestly this is the best solution.

Comment: "pm2 is the new king! forever is dead, trust me"  Perhaps you should actually explain why.  "Typically your app runs on one core. Not any more! We are talking speed!"  If that's your reason why, it's not a compelling argument.  Most Node.js apps had no problem saturating multiple CPU cores as-is.

Comment: i need to effectively pass an argument like `node ./cli.js start` is how the origina author created my setup. How would I do that with pm2?

Answer (score 2):

You could also just put forever in a user's crontab, using the @reboot parameter so it'll start when startup occurs.

something like:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/forever start /path/to/script.js
```

(This is assuming forever is in `/usr/bin/`; it may also be somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/`.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that forever keeps all of it's files in ~/.forever. The above script runs as root. Not sure where it stores them then, but for me doing "sudo forever list" does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use `start` command
        `forever start /path/to/script.js`

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `forever-service` to daemonize node.js processes, it will take care of everything by starting them on boot and log file redirection.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-service